# Mock a SQL View Result in Integration Test

Tags: grails, spock

I'm running an integration test to test the expectation of my service. What I want to do is integrate a domain class that is wired to a SQL Server view.

Obviously, I cannot insert a record (it's a view). I want to do an integration with a mocked view result set.

Is it possible to mock the view result, but still execute the service method integrated?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Unit test and use the @Mock annotation for the Domain object?

Comment: I still want the method of my service to use a data source.